# 3 level ether transfer

Tags: solidity, remix, ether, address.transfer

```
contract foster{
    vulnerable v = new vulnerable();
    attacker a = new attacker(address(v));

     constructor() public payable{

        //  a.deposit(address(v));     // transferring 3 ethers to vulnerable contract and rest to the attacker contract
        //  v.addNominee(address(a));
     }

     function action() public payable{
         a.deposit(address(v));     // transferring 3 ethers to vulnerable contract and rest to the attacker contract
         v.addNominee(address(a));
     }

     function getTargetBalance() public view returns(uint256, uint256){
        return (address(v).balance , address(this).balance);
    }

     function attack() public payable{
         v.transact();
     }
}
```

Here is what I wanna do. I have two contracts namely `attacker` and `vulnerable` with the following definitions.

### contract attacker

```
contract attacker{ 

    constructor(address payable _vulnerableContract) public{
        vulnerable v = vulnerable(_vulnerableContract);
    }

    function deposit(address payable _addr) payable public{
        _addr.transfer(msg.value);
    }

    function() external payable{
       }

}
```

### contract vulnerable

```
contract vulnerable{

    mapping (address => uint256) balance;
    uint256 _amount;

    function() external payable{
    }

    function deposit() payable public{
        address(this).transfer(_amount);
    }
}
```

---

Here in the `foster` contract, I want to create one instance each of `vulnerable` and `attacker`.

**I want to make the function `action` in the `foster` contract to call `a.deposit(address(v))`, and transfer the ethers from *a*'s behalf to contract `v`. So that the net ether is transferred from calling account to contract instance `v`.**

Then I want to add `a` as a nominee to the `v` instance.

**When I am doing the thing I have done in the contract, the ether would go to `contract foster` and not to `v`. How can I make it happen?**

*My final aim is to trigger a `failed send()` bug when I call, `v.transact`, for that I need some ethers with the `contract v`. I'll add some failure in the `function() payable` of the `contract a` later.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution found.** Thanks if someone was trying to do it.

The thing we need to do here is, after calling `a.deposit()` here in the foster contract

we need to transfer the ethers to `v`. I've added the following in the `action()` function. *It does the required thing.*

```
a.deposit(address(v));  
address(v).send(msg.value);
```

**The problem was that the ethers were first transferred to the `contract foster`, so we need to transfer it to the `contract v` after this.** It solves the problem of **3 level ether transfer.**

---

The complete solution lies here in the following gist link : 
https://gist.github.com/johnsoncarl/99d761df62da338a41ce3a3d6b162698